# How to get header value and pass it to bean property in spring-integration?

Tags: spring-integration

I am looking to get header value to pass it on bean properties in spring integration.

I have tried below steps but it is not working:

```
<bean id="loggingInterceptorId" name="loggingInterceptor" class="LoggingInterceptor">   
      <property name="id" value="#{headers.get('id')}"></property> 
</bean>
```

Comment: <bean id="id" name="test" class="com.test.PropertySetup">  
      <property name="id" value="#{headers.get('id')}"></property> 
   </bean> But it is not working,

Answer (score 0):

Try  value="headers['id']" as #{....} is reserved for property replacement.